# Spring Boot OAuth2 failed to fetch metadata from HTTPS endpoint

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I'm setting up an OAuth2 client with **spring-security-oauth2-client 5.2.2**. The client metadata is provided via an HTTPS endpoint. To be able to fetch the metadata, I have to configure a truststore at JVM level by setting `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=src/main/resources/truststore.jks`. I'm wondering if there is a way to set up a user-defined truststore for it programmatically. I found several guidelines about how to set custom SSLContext for `WebClient` while requesting for the token, however I couldn't find any hint about using custom SSLContext for fetching OAuth2's provider metadata.

I investigated spring source code and see that the `RestTemplate` used for metadata fetching is created inside `ClientRegistrations` class which gives no option for customising its behaviours: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistrations.java#L59.

While I think this is a very basic requirement for setting up OAuth2 authentication flow, am I missing something here? Is it the correct way to create a bean for `ClientRegistrationRepository` class and fetch the metadata myself?

Below is my OAuth2 configuration:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          test:
            client-id: test
            client-secret: secret
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8000/auth/callback
            scope: openid,profile
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: https://mykeycloak.com:8443/auth/realms/test
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue: I need to configure an HTTP proxy for the RestTemplate, and it seems I can't. I thought I'd simply copy the class and instantiate my own bean, but everything in ClientRegistrations is static, including the RestTemplate instance.

As a work-around, it is possible to configure the entire provider by supplying all values directly (instead of ClientRegistrations using the .well-known URLs to discover parameters from the provider), but this is not ideal.

Comment: I've now copied ClientRegistrations and OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter, and added a setter for the RestTemplate that I fill when I configure OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter (which is copied from OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration).